# rails admin customization in the labels

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

I am using rails admin for my app.

Under `rails_admin.rb`, I have something like this

```
config.model Serve do
 exclude_fields :list_id
end
```

Then in my model for `serve.rb`, I have something like this

```
class Serve < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :lists
mount_uploader :servimage, PhotoUploader
end
```

Now in the admin panel, Instead of label **Serve**, I want to rename it to **Serve Now**

So my question is, to do so, I have to change the schema? Or How can I do that?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The rails_admin configuration has label for this purpose. A different label can be used for the model to be displayed in the admin panel.

`RailsAdmin.config {|c| c.label_methods << :description}`

[rails_admin wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Models)